# Paypal MassPayout getting 403 error

Tags: java, spring, paypal

I am trying to mass payout using paypal , I getting 403 error while executing this bellow line.

```
@Autowired
private APIContext apiContext;
------------------------
------------------------
// ###Create Batch Payout 
PayoutBatch batch = payout.create(apiContext, new HashMap<String, String>());
```

See this is my config class PaypalConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class PaypalConfig {

    @Value("${paypal.client.app}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${paypal.client.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    @Value("${paypal.mode}")
    private String mode;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> paypalSdkConfig(){
        Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<>();
        sdkConfig.put("mode", mode);
        return sdkConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuthTokenCredential authTokenCredential(){
        return new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret, paypalSdkConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public APIContext apiContext() throws PayPalRESTException{
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(authTokenCredential().getAccessToken());
        apiContext.setConfigurationMap(paypalSdkConfig());
        return apiContext;
    }
}
```

This is the exception I getting.

```
com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException: Response code: 403    Error response: {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred","debug_id":"b11d9b5d1aea7","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors"}
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException.createFromHttpErrorException(PayPalRESTException.java:72)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:431)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:295)
    at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
    at com.paypal.api.payments.Payout.create(Payout.java:118)
    at com.paypal.service.impl.PaypalServiceImpl.massPayout(PaypalServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.paypal.controller.PaypalController.massPayout(PaypalController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What I missing here in authorization config ?
Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with USA account it will work.

I found answer from here : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/793

Comment: I see you took my advise and looked at the api documentation

Answer (score 1):

Http error 403 is "forbidden" which would normally imply that you don't have permission to do what you are trying to do. This is different from being not authenticated, because then you would expect a 401 "unauthorised".

I would suggest that you refer to the api documentation to see if you need to send any more data, or if there is additional config that you are missing.

Comment: that I know about 403 error , my question is what I missing here.